# PHP conditional statements within Wordpress's function.php file not working

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I want to do the following PHP statement within `function.php`: If there's an uploaded image for `#header h1 a`'s background, indent the text (remove)...If not (else), keep the text (don't indent it).

I'm not very familiar with PHP but this is what I did:

```
<?php

// Include functions of Theme Options
require_once(TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions/admin-menu.php');

// If there's an image for the site title, remove it's text
function logo_exists() {
    ?><style type="text/css">
        #header h1 a {
        <?php
        if ( $options['logo'] == NULL ) { ?>
            float: left;
            text-indent: 0;
        <?php } else { ?>
            background: url(<?php echo $options['logo']; ?>) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
            float: left;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 80px;
        }
        <?php } ?>
    </style><?php
}
```

**header.php:**

```
    // Initiate Theme Options
    $options = get_option('plugin_options');
var_dump($options['logo'])
    ?>

    <style>
        body {
            background-color: <?php echo $options['color_scheme']; ?>
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>
            <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
        </h1>
```

(I'm not sure if it is useful information but plugin_options is initialised just before the `<style>` tags.)

I did `var_dump` and `#options['logo']` displays:

```
string(63) "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/logo3.png"
```

(So the image is working)

But right now I just see the Wordpress site title

**Do I have to "activate" or "initiate" the function **logo_exists**?
or is there another problem?**

**(Everything works ok if I don't use the PHP If statements and declaring $options[logo] directly from header.php)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend to reformat your code with [if..endif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) syntax to become more readable (in mixed PHP/HTML codes).

Comment: BlotClock still has a point though, the $options variable has no scope inside your function, if you want to reference that variable inside that function you need to globalise it inside the function. The issue, i think, is that your function needs to be hook onto an appropriate action, for example `add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'logo_exists' )` to output the content into an appropriate position in header for styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$options` doesn't exist in the scope of that function. You need to add

```
global $options;
```

just after the function declaration, so that it picks up the `$options` variable from the include. Like this:

```
function logo_exists() {
    global $options;

    ?><style type="text/css">
    ...
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but still not working (still seeing the text of #header h1 a. I'm not sure if it is useful information but plugin_options is initialised just before the <style> tags.