# How to initialise CSS statements from the function.php file (Wordpress)?

Tags: wordpress, function

I have the following CSS conditional statement in my **function.php** file:

```
 function logo_exists() {
 global $options;
    ?><style type="text/css">
  #header h1 a {
  <?php
  if ( $options['logo'] == NULL ) { ?>
      float: left;
   text-indent: 0;
  <?php } else { ?>
   background: url(<?php echo $options['logo']; ?>) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
   float: left;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   width: 160px;
   height: 80px;
  }
  <?php } ?>
    </style><?php
}
```

example:

```
        (...same code as above...)

       width: 160px;
       height: 80px;
      }
      <?php } ?>
        </style><?php

        add_option('logo_exists');
```

}

I'm not sure how to "add" or "initialise" it.

I tried: add_option('logo_exists'); and add_action('logo_exists'); but it didn't work.

What's the Wordpress "add" command for conditional CSS statements in the **function.php** file?

Comment: Isn't this duplicative to your other question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482702/how-to-initialise-css-statements-from-the-function-php-file-wordpress

Comment: Oops, i meant this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482295/php-conditional-statements-within-wordpresss-function-php-file-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this variation, you could use wordpress conditions:
`is_home()` `is_singular()` (for page/article) `is_single()` `is_page()` ad so on.

Besides that, WP automatically add an extra class to `body` element and you can relate to that to build your css selectors.